# Get latest 10 products gives me the last product 10 times in Laravel8

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a New Arrivals section at the home page, but I have the following issue:

This is my controller:

```
public function home() {
    $products = Product::get();
    $newArrivals = Product::orderByDesc('id')->take(10)->get();
    return view('client.home')->with('products', $products)->with('newArrivals', $newArrivals);
}
```

I am ordering using id because I did a stupid mistake at the beginning by deleting the created_at column and I have around 1000 products now. The problem is, I am expecting to get the last 10 products but instead I am getting the last product 10 times. Do you guys have any work around for that without relying on created_at?

Comment: Is your `id` autoincrement?

Comment: if you're getting the last product 10 times, then that is what you have in your database unless you did something to it in your blade view.

Comment: I'm sure you are getting 10 latest product in $newArrivals variable. I thing you something miss in 'client.home' blade view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in your base model to ignore created_at

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

or

```
const CREATED_AT = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest() is a built-in method to handle some common practices.

```
$newArrivals = Product::latest()->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: latest depends on created_at which I have deleted by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, as @N69S suggested, it was a mistake in my blade view.